# Repeating sequence with leading zeros to make all values same length in Google Sheets

Tags: if-statement, lambda, google-sheets-formula, sequence, flatten

The following code gives a repeating sequence of specified numbers from 1 to 12, repeating it 12 times. However, the numbers generated have a different length (1,2,3...10,11,12). How can the formula be modified so that leading zeros are added in order to make all numbers the same length?

```
transpose(split(REPT(concat(JOIN(",",SEQUENCE(1,12)),","),ROUNDDOWN(ROWS(A1:A)/15)),",",true))
```

For example, in this example there are numbers with length = 2 and then the desired sequence would be 01,02...10,11,12. However if the sequence was up to 3 or more digits, for example:

```
...(",",SEQUENCE(1,150)),",")...
```

Then a desired sequence would be 001...010...150. A sequence going up to 4 would be 0001...1500 etc.

Comment: Kindly add input table and expected output table as [**text table**](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/)(NOT as IMAGE) to the question. Adding such [md tables](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) greatly increases your chances of getting a elegant answer, as **it is easier to copy/paste**. If you share spreadsheets, your question maybe closed, as questions here must be [self contained](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455). [Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), if you share Google files.

Comment: As said in my previous comment, Please don't add spreadsheet links.

Comment: Sorry. I noticed the image but I didnt read it thoroughly. I didnt realize email address was accessable by shared files, now I might have to unshare previous files. I wish there was a work around because I think it is easier than coding with pipe text for tables and easier to read. Images I suppose are because people access by mobile or also for security reasons. Anyways, thanks for your answer. Very elegant.

Comment: My first link shows a easy way to create tables with formulas(if you haven't clicked it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(TEXT(FLATTEN(MAKEARRAY(25, 12, LAMBDA(x, y, y))), "00"))
```

Answer (score 1):

`BASE` formula has `min_length` argument. You can use it to set the `LEN`gth of your sequences. It's also easy to create the sequence without `TRANSPOSE/SPLIT/JOIN/SPLIT` with just `IF/FLATTEN`. For eg, To create sequence of 12, 25 times,

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(FLATTEN(IF(SEQUENCE(25),BASE(SEQUENCE(1,12),10,LEN(12)))))
```